# Access to the properties of the Context object during Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have an EF migration that creates a linked server if it doesn't exist.  This is working well, but following this are a number of migrations that merge data in from that linked server.  Before I run these I need to issue a USE [MAIN DATABASE NAME] because I switched to MASTER to create the Linked Server.  The challenge I'm facing is that the database names are different for each environment because many of them live on the same SQL Server.  So I need to find a way to parameterize the USE statement so it switches to the appropriate database.  The upside is that the databases all have the same base name and then a - and the environment name which happens to match the name of the connection string in the config.  So the DEV database ends with -DEV and uses the connection string named DEV, QA ends with -QA and uses the QA connection string, etc...

Is there any way to read the name of the database out of the connection string or access the parameter passed to the update-database command?  Or am I missing a much better way to do this?

**EDIT:**
I'm considering using conditional compilation symbols and then doing something like this:

```
#if DEV
    SQL("USE Database-DEV");
#endif
```

but then the developers have to remember to switch solution configurations before they run update-database and sooner or later someone will forget.